# Manipular os dados JSON vindo de uma requisição do datepicker jQuery com ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datepicker

Preciso criar uma agenda.. Tenho um datepicker e uma tabela fixa ao lado com horario que começam das 08:00am até as 19:00pm e quando clico em um dia do datepicker ele me retorna todas as consultas daquele dia na tabela ao lado em seus respectivos horarios.. se tiver horario vago deve aparecer nulo..
Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo manipular os dados que o ajax me retorna (json) estou conseguindo obter os dados em array mas nao consigo coloca-los em seus devidos lugar da tabela..

segue meus códigos:

> javascript:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()  {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior',
        inline: true,

         onSelect: function () {
            var date = $("#datepicker").val();

            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST", 
                 url: "retornar_data.php",
                 data: { date: date },
                 success: function(data) {
                      $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave,valor){

                          console.log(data);

                        var lista = '<table border="1">'
                        lista += '<th> Hora </th>';
                        lista += '<th> Data </th>';
                        lista += '<th> Descrição </th>';
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>8:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>8:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>9:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>9:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>10:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>8:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>10:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>11:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>11:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>12:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>12:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>13:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>13:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>14:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>14:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>15:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>15:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>16:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>16:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>17:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>17:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>18:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>18:30</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '<td>19:00</td>'
                        lista += '<td> </td>'
                        lista += '<tr>'
                        lista += '</table>';

                     $('#teste').html(lista);


                     });



                 },
                     error: function() {
                     alert("Error.");
                 }
            });
        }
    });
});


      </script>
```

> retornar_data.php

```
<?php 


 $date = $_POST['date'];

$conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","odonto");

$selecao = "SELECT * from agenda WHERE dataAgenda = '{$date}' ";
$categorias = mysqli_query($conecta,$selecao);

$retorno = array();
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($categorias)) {
    $retorno[] = $linha;
}   

echo json_encode($retorno);

// fechar conecta
mysqli_close($conecta); ?>
```

> html:

```
 <body>


    <div id="datepicker"></div> <br>
    <div id="teste"> </div>





</body>
```

> retorno de quando clico na data:

```
[{"agendaId":"4","dentistaId":"2","dataAgenda":"2015-12-03","horaAgenda":"09:30","descricaoAgenda":"Aparelho"},{"agendaId":"8","dentistaId":"3","dataAgenda":"2015-12-03","horaAgenda":"11:30","descricaoAgenda":"Peixe"}]
```

Preciso de uma luz pra continuar estou travado depois do recebimento do parseJson..
Como posso fazer pra checar os valores recebidos verificar se contém, por exemplo, 08:30 e se sim inserir a descrição do id deste horario na tabela?

Comment: Fernando, você poderia mostrar um exemplo do retorno do json ?

Comment: oi Highlander, eu coloquei ai na pergunta já, mas de qualquer forma este é meu retorno: [{"agendaId":"4","dentistaId":"2","dataAgenda":"2015-12-03","horaAgenda":"09:30","descricaoAgenda":"Aparelho"},{"agendaId":"8","dentistaId":"3","dataAgenda":"2015-12-03","horaAgenda":"11:30","descricaoAgenda":"Peixe"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas substitua o `jsonResposta` por `data do ajax` e veja funcionar, é bem simples, apenas usei um for para percorrer o objeto e criar a tabela.

Detalhe, se você usa `json_encode` no php não há necessidade de fazer `$.parseJSON(data)` no javascript por que os dados já virão corretos.

Mudei a data no json, se você clicar no dia 22 e 03 terá agendamentos para aquela data.

```js
var jsonResposta = [{
  "agendaId": "4",
  "dentistaId": "2",
  "dataAgenda": "2015-12-22",
  "horaAgenda": "09:30",
  "descricaoAgenda": "Aparelho"
}, {
  "agendaId": "8",
  "dentistaId": "3",
  "dataAgenda": "2015-12-03",
  "horaAgenda": "11:30",
  "descricaoAgenda": "Peixe"
}];



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    prevText: 'Anterior',
    inline: true,

    onSelect: function() {
      var date = $("#datepicker").val();
      console.log(date);
      var lista = '<table border="1">';
      lista += '<th> Hora </th>';
      lista += '<th> Data </th>';
      lista += '<th> Descrição </th>';
      for (var x in jsonResposta) {
        console.log(jsonResposta[x]);
        if (date === jsonResposta[x]['dataAgenda']) {
          lista += '<tr><td>' + jsonResposta[x]['horaAgenda'] + '</td>';
          lista += '<td>' + jsonResposta[x]['dataAgenda'] + '</td>';
          lista += '<td>' + jsonResposta[x]['descricaoAgenda'] + '</td></tr>';
        }
      }
      lista += '</table>'


      $('#teste').html(lista);


    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" media="screen">
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="teste"></div>
```

Comment: desculpe eu esqueci de especificar a linha dos scripts.. eu já tenho o datepicker rodando.. o problema esta na hora que tenho o retorno dos dados que não sei como coloca-los no lugar certo da tabela

Comment: @FernandoFefu eu sei, peguei o seu retorno e to montando a resposta, isso ai é um exemplo vou edita-lo

Comment: ah tah.. valeu @Highlander

Comment: como que eu faço para manter a tabela fixa já com todos os horarios?? dai só acrescentar a descrição direto na consulta que esta agendada e as demais (que estiverem vazias) continuarem aparecendo mesmo vazias

Comment: Da forma que você esta fazendo terá que colocar todos os horários no banco de dados. é possível  deixar uma tabela predefinida com todos os horarios e sómente preenche-los com a descrição se eles estiverem no retorno do ajax, mas esta não é a pergunta.

Comment: tem alguma forma mais simples que eu possa manter essa estrutura do banco? algo do tipo um laço para percorrer o json buscando pelo horario X e se encontrar preencher a descrição no espaço X da minha tabela fixa.. mostrando sempre a tabela mesmo vazia nos outros horarios? desde já agradeço a sua atenção.